# Rails 5: How to make sure custom configuration settings are loaded on all Puma processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, settings, production-environment, puma

I'm working on an application which has a Settings model that's used to store custom configuration settings. An example of one of those values might be the quote displayed in the banner on the home page, or the email that invoices are sent to. When these values are changed, how do I make sure that every Puma process reads the updated configuration into memory?

Currently, the Settings are loaded into memory in a Rails initializer when the server boots, but I'd like to be able to also load them into memory whenever they are updated, without restarting the server.

My first thought was to store a `config_changed` flag in the database that can be checked on each request, and if the flag is true, reload the settings from the database, and then set the flag to false. But I'm not sure how to make that work with multiple Puma processes. So I just thought I'd look for some suggestions.

Comment: Maybe look into caching these settings that way you can implement a suitable TTL and then just reload them into the cache again. I am not certain what the puma process has to do with this to be honest or why these items would need to be initialized at boot and retained indefinitely

Comment: You could use something like Redis or Memcached to have high available runtime config, shared across Puma processes.